# mkfs fails to create a new xfs partition

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, partition, xfs

I am using Ubuntu LTS 12.04 server installed as a virtual machine on VMware Workstation.

Recently, I extended the logical disk.

I used sudo fdisk /dev/sdb command and i created an extended disk that i named sdb1.
When i run the fdisk -l command it shows me this:

> controller@controller:~$ sudo fdisk -l
>
> ```
> Disk /dev/sda: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes
> 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders, total 209715200 sectors
> Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
> I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
> Disk identifier: 0x000b2a4e
>
>    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
> /dev/sda1   *        2048    39845887    19921920   83  Linux
> /dev/sda2        39847934    41940991     1046529    5  Extended
> /dev/sda3        39845888    39847933        1023   8e  Linux LVM
> /dev/sda5        39847936    41940991     1046528   82  Linux swap / Solaris
>
> Partition table entries are not in disk order
>
> Disk /dev/sdb: 21.5 GB, 21474836480 bytes
> 213 heads, 34 sectors/track, 5791 cylinders, total 41943040 sectors
> Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
> I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
> Disk identifier: 0x58fc26e8
>
>    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
> /dev/sdb1            2048    41943039    20970496    5  Extended
> ```

now when i run  the

> sudo mkfs.xfs -f -i size=1024 /dev/sdb1

it shows me this:

> size 0 of data subvolume is too small, minimum 100 blocks

i don't understand what is hapening
any help would be aperciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change the partition ID... You should not have created an "extended" partition, but rather left it at the default Linux (83) ID.

Your new device/partition should look similar to this:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 480.0 GB, 480047620096 bytes
119 heads, 44 sectors/track, 179066 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 5236 * 512 = 2680832 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xf916544f

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1      179067   468795480   83  Linux
```